# Displaying jpg image on JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, jpeg

How can I display jpg image which I stored in arraylist in JPanel?
Im not able to display the jpg files in the JPanel.

```
String[] pictureFile   = {"A.jpg","B.jpg","C.jpg"};
List<String>  picList1 = Arrays.asList(pictureFile);

Collections.shuffle(picList1); 

ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("picList1.get(0)");
JLabel label1   = new JLabel();
label1.setIcon(icon);

JPanel panel = newJPanel;
panel.add(label);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not put the call to the array in quotes.

Instead, you should try the following:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(picList1.get(0));
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the line

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("picList1.get(0)");
```

It's interpreting the string as a file name. You should just need to unquote the `picList1.get(0)` bit.